# Dojo query: attribute not equal

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to match nodes that don't have an empty value attribute (value!=""). Am I supposed to use :not(...) for this and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, seems like you're on the right track there.  This seems to work in IE8, FF 3.6, recent Chrome:

```
dojo.query(':not(input[value=""])')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KaMSg/